# Python Tkinter GUI:add text from an entry widget in a pop up window to a listbox in a different window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add an entry from a toplevel window into a listbox in the main window.
So far I have managed to create a button that opens a new window containing 4 entry widgets(name, address, phone number and DOB). Is there any way, after I press the OK button on the pop up window, that all four entries are added to the listbox on the main window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something in your problem description, the OK button command just needs to copy the values from the Entry fields to the Listbox.  Was there more to it than that?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Entry, Button, Listbox

def ok_button():
    li.delete(0, "end")
    for i in range(len(fields)):
        li.insert("end", e[i].get())

root = Tk()
root.title("Listbox")

cf = Frame(root)
cf.pack()
fields = ("Name", "Address", "Phone", "DOB")
e = []
for f in fields:
    i = len(e)
    Label(cf, text=f).grid(column=2, row=i, sticky="e")
    e.append(Entry(cf, width=16))
    e[i].grid(column=4, row=i)
Button(cf, text="OK", command=ok_button).grid(column=2, row=10, columnspan=3)
li = Listbox(cf)
li.grid(column=2, row=8, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```